# There are pairs (type_id, element_id), like (1,1), (1,2), .. (5,3). How to exclude type_id from result if I need to get type ids without element_id 1?

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

I have the next table `x`:

```
id | type_id | element_id
-------------------------
1  |    1    |     1 
2  |    1    |     2
3  |    1    |     3
4  |    2    |     1
5  |    3    |     1
6  |    4    |     2
7  |    5    |     3
```

I need to get all type ids which meet condition `element_id != 1`, in other words how to get the next type_ids: [4, 5]?

If I simply do `SELECT type_id FROM x WHERE element_id != 1`, I receive [1, 1, 4, 5].

Comment: What's your expect result and what would you want to do?

Comment: @D-Shih. I need to get all the id of types that do not contain an element with id 1. Expected result: [4,5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the condition aggregate function in `HAVING` which didn't contain any `element_id = 1` from type_id

```
SELECT type_id 
FROM x
GROUP BY type_id 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN element_id = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=76f526ff7407532cb6e0410727db3814)

Or using filter clause with aggregate function

```
SELECT type_id 
FROM x
GROUP BY type_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE element_id = 1 ) = 0
```

Comment: BTW Is there any difference between the first and second option?

Comment: @Prosto_Oleg I think they might be the same,  we can see the execution plan https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=36633973394be6f2c072cb53282d8935